# About Kirby Diagrams

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, kirby-diagram

I'm reading [R.E. Gompf and A.I. Stipsicz, *4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ahLKzRUTBbUC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). There is something I don't understand on page 116 ([Google Books link to page 116](http://books.google.com/books?id=ahLKzRUTBbUC&pg=PA116); alternatively, here are images of [page 115](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36sAV.png) and [page 116](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRq2l.png))

Now, we consider compact 4-manifolds, and they have handle decomposition.
0-handle and $m$ 1-handles form $X_{1}$, which is diffeomorphic to $\natural m S^1 \times D^3$. Let $X_{2}$ be $X_{1}\cup $ 2-handles. I understand those facts, but I can't understand 
$$\partial X_{2}=\partial(\natural m S^1 \times D^3).$$
If you can help me, then please teach me the reason for this.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the naturals to sharps, but then I realized Gompf and Stipsicz used naturals! So I reverted to Zev Chonoles's edit.

Comment: Apparently I earned the "cleanup" badge for cleaning up my own mistake. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use duality to notice that the union of $3$ and $4$ handles must be isomorphic to some handlebody $\natural nS^1\times D^3$. (Here $m$ doesn't have to equal $n$. If you look at the book carefully, it uses both $n$ and $m$.) Recall that a $k$-handle can be thought of as an $(n-k)$-handle if you read the decomposition backward. (This is the dual decomposition.) Thus the $3$ and $4$ handles represent $0$ and $1$-handles in the dual decomposition. The union of the rest of the handles must attach to the boundary of this, so their boundary must equal $\partial(\natural nS^1\times D^3)$.

Comment: Okay,I see that,but I can't understand that 3-,4-handles and 0-,1-,2-handles must have the same boundary.Why?

Comment: Because you are gluing them together to get a closed manifold.

Comment: Oh,I see.Thanks:-)